# User tutorial in react native

Tags: react-native

How can I create a user manual in React Native?

Once some condition is triggered, I want to run a tutorial where a certain view/element will be highlighted and remain touchable, while the rest of the screen will turn dark and make it untouchable. After clicking on this element, I want to go to the next screen or perform another interaction with the selected object and so on.

I found react-native-copilot, but it does not look like what I want.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.